# Ubuntu 22.04 unable to upload files using chrome or firefox

Tags: browser, ubuntu-22.04

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

When I try to upload files using any browser the website does nothing.

[image: screenshot of file upload]

In the above image if I click on Add file then "select files from your device".

My file manager does not open.

Drag and drop is working but not a lot of sites support that feature.

When I tried using chrome, the file manager window would launch but after selecting a file the browser would freeze.

I have tried a few fixes:

- Refreshing the browser (firefox)
- Downloading java plugin add-on
- Installing `xdg-desktop-portal` , `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` , `ubuntu-restricted-extras` through terminal.

These are the links which I used to try resolving this problem:

1. [Ubuntu 10.10 , I tried this fix but couldn't find iced-tea plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54343/unable-to-upload-files-via-any-browser-or-application)
2. [This is the exact problem I face](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414364/lubuntu-22-04-firefox-upload-window-not-showing-and-download-issues)
3. [I tried this fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558297/unable-to-upload-files-with-any-browser-on-ubuntu-14-04-why)

Comment: Chrome uses GTK as the UI framework, while Ubuntu uses QT. It seems that Ubuntu's desktop environment does not have GTK components.

Answer (score 23):

I ran into the same issue, and noticed that when I tried it with Chrome this would cause it to hang. Searching for *that* brought me to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404550/google-chrome-freeze-uploading-a-file
which suggests:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

This did the trick for me, seems to be a known issue in 22.04 right now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it disabling hardware acceleration in Google Chrome